# Javascript ternary operator not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have this function. It uses a callback function to find the arrays first value matching criteria (n>5), and then returns the rest of the array if found.

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  var newArr = arr.filter(func);
  return newArr==[] ? newArr : arr.slice(arr.indexOf(newArr[0]),arr.length);
}

dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n > 5;});
```

I want the expected result to be

> []

but for some reason I am getting the value of

> [4]

Comment: You want `newArr.length == 0` for the condition

Comment: On the right hand side of `newArr==[]`, there is a _new_ Array object created from literal... Not identical to any other array.

Comment: Btw, you really should use `findIndex` instead of `filter`+`indexOf`

Comment: thanks bergi  and marekful for the advice ;)